# Odoo 12 - form responsive conditional

Tags: python, odoo-12

I need to render a form to mobile. The main idea is to dynamically parse the form.

Any ideas?
This is the main idea:

```
if (isMobile) {
    <web-mobile></web-mobile>
}
else {
    <web-desktop></web-desktop>
}
```

I got the device vía Javascript, using

```
var config = require('web.config');
    config.device.isMobile;
```

but i need parse the form via template. This is possible???

Comment: Why not simply use responsive CSS classes? Odoo default web client is Bootstrap based so it wouldn't be hard